Access macOs app info in Kotlin Multiplatform project
I'm developing a Compose Multiplatform, where I need to access packageName/bundleId from android and apple(ios and macOs) platform.
build.gralde.kts (composeApp)
kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "${JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8}"
                freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjdk-release=${JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8}"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    listOf(
        macosX64(),
        macosArm64(),
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.uiTooling)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activityCompose)
        }

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependsOn(macosMain.get())
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            }
        }
    }
}

commonMain
expect val bundleId: String

androidMain
actual val bundleId: String
    get() = packageInfo.applicationInfo?.loadLabel(packageManager)?.toString().orEmpty()

iosMain
actual val bundleId: String
    get() = NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier.orEmpty()

macosMain
actual val bundleId: String
    get() = NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier.orEmpty() // Not able to access macos native api's

In macosMain sourcet I'm not able to access macos specific API's, if I make jvmMain depends on macosMain sourceSet.
Note : As I'll not able to access macOs properties inside jvmMain so I've marked jvmMain depends on macosMain sourceSet, and add implementation inside macosMain and access that class/property inside jvmMain for actual implementation.
If I remove depends on line from jvmMain sourceSet then I'm able to access macos platform API's inside macosMain sourceSet.
